# Selecting a subset of rows for each date

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in a MySQL database, which contains events.

I need to select events for one month (e.g. from December 10 to January 10) with a limit of 5 events for each day. (Event time is stored as timestamp).

Can I implement this with one query or do I have to launch 30 different queries?

Comment: If a given day has 6 events, how do you choose which one is ruled out?

Comment: OP, were you ever to work this one out or are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want the `greatest_n_per_group`. There is a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) for that on this site.

For this example, you didn't specify which 5 events you want to select in the case that there are more than 5 events per day. For my example, let's consider you want to select the events with the 5 highest ids for the day. I ran the following into SQL Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  eventDate DATE);

INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-10');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-10');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-10');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-10');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-10');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-10');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-15');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-15');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-15');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-15');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-15');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-20');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-20');
INSERT INTO events (eventDate) VALUES ('2014-12-20');
```

If you counted through, 6 events occurred on 12/10 (id 1-6), 5 events on 12/15 (id 7-11) and 3 events on 12/20 (id 12-14).

Based on my expected output, I should see only ids 2-6 for events on 12/10, and all events on the other two days. That can be accomplished with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM events ev
       WHERE ev.eventDate = e.eventDate AND ev.id >= e.id) <= 5
  AND e.eventDate BETWEEN '2014-12-10' AND '2015-01-10';
```

This does something similar to a self join, looking at each date, and filtering by selecting the largest id (done by the condition `ev.id >= e.id`) as long as the number of rows for each date doesn't exceed 5.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cd3a7/2) example.